# jsTree jquery plugin is not working in mvc 5?

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-5, jstree

Trying to use jsTree in my asp.net mvc 5 project. But could not figure out why is it not working?  Here is fiddle link as well. https://dotnetfiddle.net/24h7Nm.

Controller:-

```
 public ActionResult ShowTree()
 {
            return View();
 }
```

View:-

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowTree";
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.1.0/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<script>
$(function () {
    $("#divTree").jstree();  
});

</script>
<h2>ShowTerms</h2>

<div id="divTree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Root node 11
            <ul>
                <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
                <li>Child node 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Root node 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.1.0/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use `$` before jQuery is available. Move the `<script>` block down, like so:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "ShowTree";
}
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.1.0/themes/default/style.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<h2>ShowTerms</h2>

<div id="divTree">
    <ul>
        <li>
            Root node 11
            <ul>
                <li id="child_node_1">Child node 1</li>
                <li>Child node 2</li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li>Root node 2</li>
    </ul>
</div>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jstree/3.1.0/jstree.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/app.js"></script>
<script>
$(function () {
    $("#divTree").jstree();  
});
</script>
```